# Two Bootstrap nav menus at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I like to know if its possible to have two nav's at the same time.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2tYu/) with the bootstrap test with only the collapse JavaScript for the navbar. Both menus get expanded at the same time, is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I get the feeling that the repro can be made more minimal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can, all you have to do is differentiate the `data-target` attribute with a unique class  or id for your dropdown menus like so:

For your first dropdown

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#first">
```

For your second dropdown:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#second">
```

Then you can add that unique id to your nav collapse container:

First

```
<div id="first" class="nav-collapse"> ... </div>
```

Second

```
<div id="second" class="nav-collapse"> ... </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F2tYu/3/

Comment: Omg am i sleeping, its that easy. God next time i look at it b4 i open a SO Question ;)

Comment: Please use HTML window for BODY tag